# Можно ли писать вопросы через запятую или грамотнее по отдельным предложениям?

Tags: пунктуация, стилистика

Например:

> А как же твоё настроение, придёшь сегодня?

Или:

> А как же твоё настроение? Придёшь сегодня?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: **А как же твое настроение? Придешь сегодня?**

Здесь дело не в грамотности, а в содержании, в понимании коммуникативной задачи сказанного.

Пример 1.  **А как же наша встреча, придешь сегодня?**

**Вопросы объединены**, потому что раскрывают **одну тему**: подтверждение уже назначенной встречи при возможно изменившихся обстоятельствах. Это **однородные** по смыслу вопросы (ключевые слова: ***встреча, придёшь***).

Пример 2.  **А как же твое настроение? Придешь сегодня?**

Здесь ситуация другая. Изменились обстоятельства, изменилось настроение, и это может помешать встрече.  Состоится она или нет? Это **неоднородные** по смыслу вопросы (ключевые слова: ***настроение; придешь***).

**Поэтому вопросы разделены, их сложно перечислить в одной фразе:**

(1) А как же твое настроение (оно не помешает нашей встрече)? (2) Придешь сегодня?

**ВЫВОД**

Логично объединять **однородные** по смыслу вопросы, которые имеют сходное содержание, раскрывают одну тему. Если вопросы **неоднородные** (они просто связаны одной темой, но отношения между ними, к примеру, причинно-следственные), то надо задавать каждый вопрос отдельно..

**Правило Розенталя** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88#pp88

Вопросительный знак ставится в конце бессоюзного сложного предложения, если **все образующие его части являются вопросительными предложениями** (между ними ставятся **запятые**): **Кто скачет, кто мчится под хладною мглой? (Жук.)** или только последняя часть содержит прямой вопрос (перед ней ставится двоеточие либо тире, в зависимости от смысловых отношений между частями предложения): А я ехала сейчас, говорила с вами и всё думала: почему они не стреляют? (Сим.); Хвалы приманчивы — как их не пожелать? (Кр.)

Как мы видим, **у Розенталя запятая поставлена между однородными по смыслу предложениями.**

Answer (score 2):

Здесь возможен вариант с двумя раздельными вопросами, но смысловая связь между ними и то обстоятельство, что предположительно ожидается один ответ (настроена ли девушка прийти) делает логичным объединение их в одно предложение. При выборе знака препинания между частями нужно учитывать 
следующее:

> 5. Вопросительный знак ставится в конце бессоюзного сложного предложения, если все образующие его части являются вопросительными
>      предложениями (между ними ставятся запятые): *Кто скачет, кто мчится
>      под хладною мглой? (Жуковский)*
>
> http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88#pp88

Формально это правило позволяет обойтись **запятой**, но можно найти основания и для **тире**:

> В бессоюзном сложном предложении тире между частями обычно ставится в
>   тех случаях, когда основная часть высказывания (соответствующая иногда
>   главной части сложноподчиненного предложения) содержится во второй
>   части сложного предложения, а первая часть (соответствующая
>   придаточной части) имеет подчиненное по смыслу значение, указывая
>   время или условие совершения действия, о котором идет речь во второй
>   части, иногда причину, уступку и т. д.
>
> http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151

В нашем случае приход девушки (вторая часть) зависит от её настроения (первая часть), а содержание вопроса сводится к тому, придёт ли она в результате. Поэтому логичен и вариант с тире:

> А как же твоё настроение - придёшь сегодня?

Выбор между тремя вариантами (раздельно, с запятой или с тире) может зависеть от *контекста*:  из текста самого вопроса не вполне ясно, напр. какой смысл добавляет частица "же". Я предположил, что у девушки ранее было плохое настроение, а вопрос в том, не придёт ли она несмотря на это, - с надеждой, что её настроение уже улучшилось или просто переменилось с "не ходить" на "пойти". Без частицы "же" я бы предположил, что второй вопрос просто уточняет первый, и поставил бы запятую.

Comment: А как же твоё настроение - придёшь сегодня? Мне это предложение кажется некорректным. По Розенталю при постановке тире первая часть не является вопросительной.